# Testing Angular using Angular Mocks: Provider '$$sanitizeUri' must define $get factory method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm testing my application using Angular Mocks and when it tries to create some module I have this issue.

```
describe('navRegisterOverrideSpec', function () {
  var navigationServiceProvider;

  beforeEach(module('wrapper'));

  describe('remove un needed navs', function () {
    var navigationService;

    beforeEach(
      inject(function ($injector) {
        navigationService = $injector.get('navigationService');
      }));

    it('Should not have admin menu', function () {
      var filtered = _.filter(navigationService.items, function (item) {
        return item.id == 'admin_menu';
      });

      expect(filtered.length).toEqual(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Below is the error I got.

> 

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$injector:pget] Provider '$$sanitizeUri' must define $get factory method.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/pget?p0=%24%24sanitizeUri
    at provider (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4497)
    at D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:366
    at forEach (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336)
    at D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4484
    at ngModule (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2530)
    at invoke (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4665)
    at runInvokeQueue (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4558)
    at D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4567
    at forEach (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322)
    at loadModules (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4590)
    at createInjector (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4470)
    at workFn (D:/Projects/l35workflow/src/portals/verybest/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2464)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Apget%5D%20Provider%20'%
```

I cannot find any answer out there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this very same issue and stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13939) github issue which then lead me to the [linked](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13794) github issue. I have no idea whether or not you are using karma as your test runner and phantom as your headless web browser but updating my `karma-phantomjs-launcher` to `^1.0.0` ultimately solved my issue.

Reason for the issue (for those who don't want to go through the links I mentioned above) is that PhantomJS is not officially supported by the Angular and in turn the older version of the `karma-phantomjs-launcher` was using an older web engine that handled new/bind differently than what Angular is used to.

Comment: Sadly, does not solve the issue for me. Fails in the exactly same way when running against Chrome. Bizarre...

Comment: Sorry it didn't help your issue. Lost a lot of time on the problem myself so I figured I'd post my solution. If you are using `karma-phantomjs-launcher` and tried to update I'd definitely make sure you're clearing the npm cache (`npm clear cache`) beforehand

Comment: I had exactly this exception, to fix I did not change karma-phantomjs-launcher but just included this polyfill: https://github.com/tom-james-watson/phantomjs-polyfill/blob/master/bind-polyfill.js